# what will be the output of printf("%d","Hello"+1);?

Tags: c

I am running a c program that includes the statement :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main() {
  printf("%d","Hello"+1);  
}
```

it gives 4196445 as output.Is it correct..please explain the logic

Comment: Why are you doing this? It's not defined behavior, and it wouldn't make much sense to do it even if it were well-defined. What are you *trying* to do?

Comment: not sure it is undefined behaviour or not, but what happening is `"Hello"` is `const char *` and `+1` to it make an `int` so it is printing the address of literal string `"Hello"` plus one

Comment: @BryanChen: Adding 1 to a pointer doesn't make it an int. It's pointer arithmetic; the result is still a pointer.

Comment: @BryanChen you should make your comment an answer, no? I'd +1 it.

Comment: @BryanChen: A pointer plus an integer is still a pointer in C. The pointer is passed to the variadic function as raw data, but is then interpreted by that function as int. I think using the wrong data type for a format specifier is undefined behaviour. (So the standards committee is on the safe side.)

Comment: @Spundun looks like my comment is wrong... and thanks to others for point it out

Comment: it prints out the address of "ello"

Comment: The size of a pointer is not necessarily that of an int. It may very well be that `4196445` is not even the correct address.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Or it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although some would say "it is undefined behavior according to the standard", here is what happens de-facto. Please note that it's a very general description, which may be slightly different depending on your platform (compiler, CPU architecture, operating system, MMU, standard-output controller, etc):

- The compiler generates a null-terminated string of characters (`"Hello"`), and places it in the code-section (RO-data section to be more accurate) of your program.
- Every time a process is created and the executable image is loaded into memory (i.e., whenever you run your program), a string containing the characters 
  `'H'`,`'e'`,`'l'`,`'l'`,`'o'`,`'\0'` resides at the logical memory address 4196444. The physical memory address of this string can be calculated by adding that value to the value of the Base-Address register (although this should be of no concern to you, as your program is oblivious to that).
- Since **the logical address** of this string will remain 4196444 throughout **every** execution of your program, the compiler can replace the calculation of `"Hello"+1` with the constant value 4196445.
- So you can imagine that instead of compiling `printf("%d","Hello"+1)`, the compiler has compiled `printf("%d",4196445)`. In fact, since the `"%d"` string is also a constant string located in the code-section of your program, it is also replaced with some constant value.
- BTW, if you were using a variable pointing to the `"Hello"` string, then the compiler, unable to determine that value during compilation, would generate code to compute it during runtime instead. The computation itself would be performed using either the stack or general-purpose registers (or possibly a combination of both). Here is a typical example of how this value would be calculated through the stack (which is another section of your program - similar to the code-section, but with write-permission):

  - The value of the variable is pushed into the stack.
  - The value 1 is pushed into the stack.
  - The first two elements are popped from the stack and added.
  - The result is pushed back into the stack.
- In any case, when `printf("%d","Hello"+1)` is invoked:

  - The address of the string `"%d"` is pushed into the stack.
  - The address of the string `"Hello"` plus 1 is pushed into the stack.
  - The Program Counter (or as some call it - Instruction Pointer) jumps to the address of function `printf` in memory, and execution continues from there.
  - For every `%` character in the string pointed by the first argument passed to function `printf`, the function loads the corresponding argument from the stack, and then - based on the type specified after the `%` character - computes the data to be printed.
  - Finally, the outcome is sent to the screen (to be more accurate, for every character in the outcome, a standard-output interrupt is generated, causing the PC (Program Counter) / IP (Instruction Pointer) to jump to the IV (Interrupt Vector), where a designated ISR (Interrupt Service Routine), which is essentially a function just like any other function in your code, is invoked, and in turn writes the input character into the FIFO queue of the standard-output controller).

---

**As implied by @hvd in one of the comments below:**

On a 64-bit system, `%d%` would truncate the result of `"Hello"+1` from a 64-bit value to a 32-bit value. Using `%lld` would fix that, but of course - the correct solution is to use `%p`.

Comment: Who spam-downvoted and why? Questions and answers stand on their own merits, and this is a _high-quality answer_, even though the _question's quality_ is _debatable_. If you dislike the question, downvote the question.

Comment: @Iwillnotexist Idonotexist: Thank you for your support. This down-vote once again leads me to believe that detailed answers with a lot of investment put into them are not always... well... worth the effort (here is a blog-post on that http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow). Of course, if this doesn't change then I'll remove the answer shortly.

Comment: It's probably better to just not worry about downvoters. Anyway, something that is not part of your answer but could be is what happens on systems with 64-bit pointers, and 32-bit int, becoming more and more common, and for all we know, the OP may be using such an implementation. Still undefined (of course), but what commonly happens is that the first 32 bits of the pointer are displayed  as an integer (where "first" depends on endianness).

Comment: @hvd: Hmmm... Certainly worth mentioning that (i.e., on 64-bit systems, `%d%` would truncate the result). Thanks.

Comment: In my view the only correct answer here is that it's undefined behaviour. Anything else is simply encouraging people to incorrectly blur the line between "my compiler" and C. Even on x86 nothing prevents a conforming implementation from using a calling convention that passes pointers differently from integers. That's the whole point of UB and totally missed by this answer.

Comment: Thank you @Flexo. Please notice the "here is what happens de-facto" which follows the "undefined behavior" statement. It is there to explain the output observed by OP, **even though** the code may yield undefined behavior according to the standard. It is undefined by the standard, yet de-facto, something happens - `4196445` is printed on the screen. OP wants to know why, so the answer explains it in great details. Although it is possible that OP is really interested in the ANSI-C standard, the question at hand suggests that he or she are merely trying to explain their observation.

Answer (score 4):

> what will be the output of printf(“%d”,“Hello”+1);?

Others claimed that it will "print the address of the string plus one". That **may or may not be true.** The reason for this is that **your code invokes undefined behavior,** because you are printing an object of type `char *` with a format specifier suited for `int` only.

So, the compiler and subsequently the code can do anything it pleases (including erasing your hard disk or downloading the latest Justin Bieber album.)

Answer (score -2):

This will print the value of 
      ( address of string ("Hello") + 1 )

So, In your case base address of string "Hello" is 4196444.
That's why output is printed 4196445.